XSLT tokenize with regular expression to only tokenize if the semi-colon is not followed by a space and a number
I am trying to tokenize this string to create separate entries for each bibliographic citation. The catch is that sometimes the semi-colon separate a bibliographic entry and sometimes it separates page numbers. I want to write the tokenizer to only tokenize if the semi-colon is not followed by a space and a number. What I have below, sort of works, but it cuts of the first letter of each citation. (I'm using XSLT 2.0)
Input:
  <zotero>(Leppin 2019; Francisco 2011, 119; van Ginkel 2005, 43–44; 1995, 114–115; 126; 147; 166–67)</zotero>

XSLT:
<xsl:for-each select="tokenize(zotero,';\s[^\d]')">
 <bibl><xsl:value-of select="."/></bibl>
</xsl:for-each>

Current Output:
<bibl>(Leppin 2019</bibl>
<bibl>rancisco 2011, 119</bibl>
<bibl>an Ginkel 2005, 43–44; 1995, 114–115; 126; 147; 166–67)</bibl>



I want to write the tokenizer to only tokenize if the semi-colon is
not followed by a space and a number

With a negative lookahead that would be expressed as
  <xsl:template match="zotero">
    <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(., ';(?! [0-9])', ';j')">
      <bib>{.}</bib>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

That ;j flags works with Saxon Java, SaxonC, Saxon .NET, SaxonCS and SaxonJS to switch to from standards XPath regular expression to the platform supported.

Perfect! Thank you for the help, this does exactly what I need.

Unfortunately the XPath specification does not allow for lookahead in regular expressions.
You could use a workaround like:
<xsl:variable name="preprocess" select="replace(zotero, ';\s(\D)', '&#133;$1')" />
<xsl:for-each select="tokenize($preprocess, '&#133;')">
    <bibl>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </bibl>
</xsl:for-each>

Or, if you are using the Saxon processor, you can switch to the standard Java regular expression engine and do simply:
<xsl:for-each select="tokenize(zotero, ';\s(?=\D)', ';j')">


This is great! Thanks for the alternative solution. I am using Saxon so I can use the ':j' flag, but I like the workaround solution also.

Rather than use the tokenize function I would probably use xsl:analyze-string like so:
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="true"/>

<xsl:template match="zotero">
  <listBibl>
    <!-- each bibl starts with at least one letter \p{L} or space \p{Z},
    and continues with an optional sequence of non-letters \P{L} -->
    <xsl:analyze-string 
      select="substring(., 2, string-length(.) - 2)" 
      regex="(\p{{L}}|\p{{Z}})+\P{{L}}*"
    >
      <xsl:matching-substring>
        <bibl><xsl:value-of select="."/></bibl>
      </xsl:matching-substring>
    </xsl:analyze-string>
  </listBibl>
</xsl:template>
 
</xsl:stylesheet>

Yielding:
<listBibl>
   <bibl>Leppin 2019; </bibl>
   <bibl>Francisco 2011, 119; </bibl>
   <bibl>van Ginkel 2005, 43–44; 1995, 114–115; 126; 147; 166–67</bibl>
</listBibl>

The trouble with tokenize() is that it eats your delimiters, unlike <xsl:analyze-string> (or in XSLT 3, the analyze-string() function). I think this approach is easier to extend e.g. into a nested set of analyze-string statements that generate more granular bibliographic markup such as e.g. <date> and <citedRange> elements.

Thanks, this is also a very helpful solution.
